# Can I check if a primary key exists within a SQLite table? [python]

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating a login system and using a SQLite3 database in python. I have a table called users, containing the username and password that a user enters when creating an account. The username is the primary key. How can I check if a username already exists in the table, allowing me to prompt the user to choose a different name? Thanks.

Comment: add more info pls. Info like : which connector are You using ?  are You using any ORM or You do it by Custom-SQL ?

Comment: @rossc In Android you iterate over the meta data this will tell you a lot You might search of code that does the same in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
cur=con.cursor()

#----------*****----------#
while True:
        user_nm=input('Username: ')
        if user_nm and user_nm.strip():
            user_nm=(user_nm.strip(),)
            query='select exists(select 1 from users where username=? collate nocase) limit 1'
            # 'query' RETURNS 1 IF USERNAME EXISTS OR 0 IF NOT, AS INTEGER(MAYBE). 'collate nocase'= CASE INSENSITIVE, IT'S OPTIONAL
            check=cur.execute(query,user_nm) 
            if check.fetchone()[0]==0:
                print('Username avalaible')
                break
            else:
                try_again=input('Username is not available, try again (any key)/stop (s): ').lower() 
                if try_again=='s':
                    break
        else:
            print('Input something')
```

Comment: Don't really recommend a `While True` clause, a simple exception can cause an infinite loop.